# How to maintain aspect ratio of datagridview column width when win form resize

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have one win form and there is one grid. Grid dock property is set to **fill**. When I bind my grid with data then I also mention all column width like this way.

```
dgList.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

dgList.Columns[0].Width = 100;
dgList.Columns[1].Width = 100;
dgList.Columns[2].Width = 262;
dgList.Columns[3].Width = 530;
```

So I like to know when I will resize my form then grid height & width will also increase proportionately. So when grid height & width will change then I want to increase or decrease the column with proportionately as per previous column width. So how to achieve it. Thanks.

### i got some code from stackoverflow and those are good for calculating aspect ratio

```
1) var gcd = GCD(A, B);
return string.Format("{0}:{1}", A / gcd, B / gcd)

And a very basic function for calculating the GCD, using the Euclidean algorithm:

static int GCD(int a, int b) {
    return b == 0 ? a : GCD(b, a % b);
}

2)
public int GCD(int a, int b)

{
    while (a != 0 && b != 0)
    {
         if (a > b)
            a %= b;
         else
            b %= a;
    }
     if (a == 0)
         return b;
     else
         return a;
}

// Using Konrad's code: 

var gcd = GCD(A, B);
return string.Format("{0}:{1}", A / gcd, B / gcd)

3)
private int FindHCF(int m, int n)
 {
     int temp, reminder;
     if (m < n)
     {
         temp = m;
         m = n;
         n = temp;
     }
     while (true)
     {
         reminder = m % n;
         if (reminder == 0)
             return n;
         else
             m = n;
         n = reminder;
     }
 }

So here is the rest of the code

int hcf = FindHcf(835, 625);
int factorW = 835 / hcf;
int factorH = 625 / hcf;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely to be looking for [DataGridViewColumn.FillWeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.fillweight.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

For all the columns, set `AutoSizeMode` property to fill. Once done, on resizing form, columns will also increase and decrease in width proportionately.

Comment: i will specify the col width and also want to set calculated col width when form resize and datagridview will increase.

Comment: In that case, you should use Resize event handler.